# Issue with developing Lightning componenets using Mavensmate IDE for Sublime Text

Tags: lightning, mavensmate

For developing Lightning componenets I am using Mavensmate IDE for Sublime Text but it overwrites changes of other developers in the dev sandbox, although it is checking for conflicts for Apex classes. Is this a Mavensmate limitation or Tooling API limitation

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking for conflicts between the server version and the local version is implemented by MavensMate. (See [GitHub](https://github.com/joeferraro/MavensMate/blob/8804517bf8f8edf716405d959abc5f9468aa021f/app/lib/services/compile.js)).

This issue, however, really reflects a development process issue. I would suggest you remedy it by applying different practices for managing team development, like

- Provisioning additional Developer sandboxes so developers do not conflict with one another.
- Using version control pervasively, and performing server deployments to shared sandboxes only from an integration branch after developer code has been checked in and merged.
- Using development tools that are currently supported, such as Visual Studio Code with the Salesforce extension pack, or any of the current commercial offerings. MavensMate is unsupported and discontinued.
- Modularizing code and stories so that developers are not working on the same units at the same time.

I would encourage you not to rely on modification date checks as your only route to avoid overwrite conflicts. In addition to being unreliable, it doesn't provide any support once a conflict has been identified. The true remedy is going to involve changes to development practices to manage and share code revisions effectively.

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully, you are aware of [where Salesforce is putting its effort](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2018/02/salesforce-extensions-vs-code.html):

> ...the **Salesforce Extensions for VS Code** are the future of Salesforce
>   development. We are dedicating our resources to make this the best and
>   most enjoyable desktop editor for Salesforce developers.

When you combine this tooling with SFDX scratch orgs and Git, multiple developers working in parallel becomes a much safer process. The whole development process goes faster, and the tools get in the way less than they have in the past.

So my suggestion is that you plan to move over to these tools which are where most of the innovation is now.